# How can I get all currently running nodes from the master in rosjava?

Tags: ros, nodes, rosjava, rosmaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a simple way to retrieve all currently running nodes from the ros master in rosjava?
In order to obtain all topics in the system the following works:

```
MasterClient masterClient = new MasterClient(this.node.getMasterUri());
Response<SystemState> systemState = masterClient.getSystemState(defaultNodeName);
List<TopicSystemState> topicSystemStateList = systemState.getResult().getTopics();
```

Is there something similar to obtain all running nodes?
The only way I found is to indirectly retrieve them via TopicSystemState.getPublishers() and TopicSystemState.getSubscribers() - but this would ignore nodes which do not subscribe or publish anything.

Regards scr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42869/how-can-i-get-all-currently-running-nodes-from-the-master-in-rosjava?/) by [sacrif](https://answers.ros.org/users/2262/sacrif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While the underlying information is available, much of the master API is not yet exposed as a public API. Feel free to file a feature request.

http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0